# Android textview.setText() loses gravity?

Tags: textview, android

I have a simple layout that contains a TextView between two ImageViews.

When I change the TextView at runtime with 'setText()', it changes but it loses the "center_horizontal" gravity and it is drawn at the top of the linear layout.

How can I make the TextView be drawn at the "center_horizontal" gravity after "setText()"?

```
</RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl1"
    style="@style/style1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

        ...        

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/frame"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="@drawable/white" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon" />

    </LinearLayout>
        ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The `setText` method normally does not influence the layout ordering.
I currently can only think of one possible problem:
Your set text is either very long or very short and as you specified the dimensions as "wrap_content" the width and height of your textview aligns to the new content. This results in a new layout merging. 
To solve this you could do the following:

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="@drawable/white" />
```

Comment: I made a mistake in the question, but the problem is the same. The attribute is android:gravity="center_vertical". I tried it your way and defined the layout_height (instead of width) to 'fill_parent'. My text is a few digits long. It still loses the gravity...

Comment: Can you add the actual java code where you are setting the new text?

Comment: The setText() placed in a Handler:
handler = new Handler() {
      public void handleMessage(Message msg) {  
 String res = msg.getData().getString("data"); 
 textview.setText(res);  
      };